# Apache tomcat weird behaviour

Tags: java, tomcat, lag

I have a web based software which i deploy to a tomcat container. Usually there are 200 users working simultaniously inside the application.

The problem that i am experiancing is the following:

When i decide to **stop the application AND then start it again** the CPU goes to 100% and the tomcat container starts lagging and it takes ages to log in into the program and start working again. Obviously this must be because of the users who are trying to connect again BUT when i **undeploy the application and then deploy it again and start it** then no matter that the users are logging in simultaniously there is absolutelly no lag!

What can i do so i improve this?

P.S. I am using the latest version of tomcat - currently 8

Comment: Are you using the tomcat manager to stop/start? I haven't tried Tomcat 8, but using the manager to restart has always caused us problems (memory problems) and we had to give up using it. We only do complete shutdowns and restarts of Tomcat. We spent ages trying to solve this with various programmes to study the memory but after wasting eons on it we gave up using the manager.

Comment: Exactly! I am using the web based manager.

Comment: When Tomcat7 came along we were hopeful they might have found the answer to the problem because they improved the messages about memory, but the problems continued so we gave up the manager. It would be very convenient indeed if it worked, but we never solved the problem despite a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1):

When you undeploy any appliaction it remove the .war file from the webapps directory but the exploded directory doesn't get removed (the WEB-INF/lib folder).

Just put this in your context.xml file in your_tomcat_home_directory/Config:

```
<Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
```

for details read about antiJARLocking & antiResourceLocking at

```
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html
```

Comment: <Context antiJARLocking="true" antiResourceLocking="true">

Comment: When i click edit I can see it but when I finish it disappears :(